# Make img not to move in html

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, onmousemove

I have an image on my page, and I would like to listen to onmousemove events when the mouse is down. But I can't because in my browser (Firefox), when I drag an image, well actually I drag the image, which I don't want.

Here's my code:

JavaScript part:

```
document.onmousemove=getMouseCoordinates;

var x;
var y;
var clicked = false;

function getMouseCoordinates(event){
    ev = event || window.event;
    x = ev.pageX;
    y = ev.pageY;
}

    function onClickMap(){  
        var obj = document.getElementById("selectArea");
        var tempX = x;
        var tempY = y;

    obj.style.left = tempX + "px";
    obj.style.top  = tempY + "px";

    clicked = true;
}

function onMoveMap(){
    if(clicked){
        var obj = document.getElementById("selectArea");
        var xToSize = Math.abs(parseInt(obj.style.left) - x);
        var yToSize = Math.abs(parseInt(obj.style.top)  - y);
        obj.style.width  = xToSize + "px";
        obj.style.height = yToSize + "px";
    }
}
```

HTML part:

```
<img src="pixels.png" id ="pixelDiv" usemap="#pixelMap" onClick="onClickMap()" onmousemove="onMoveMap()">
```

Comment: you dont want your image to be dragged?

Comment: You can use the CSS `-webkit-user-drag:none;` but it's only supported by webkit atm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a jQuery solution.

This will disable all drags:

```
$(document).bind("dragstart", function() {
     return false;
});
```

If you want to disable drags only on `img` elements:

```
$(document).bind("dragstart", function(e) {
     if (e.target.nodeName.toUpperCase() == "IMG") {
         return false;
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a mousedown handler that just returns false. This seems to stop the dragging in FF.

Answer (score 0):

ok it's nice, but I suppose it is something firefox specific, now I disabled the onlcick and onmove methods of my image, but I can stil drag the image

now I've found the solution, I was looking for this

[http://www.develobert.info/2008/10/disable-firefox-image-drag.html](http://www.develobert.info/2008/10/disable-firefox-image-drag.)